# How do I push a Docker image to amazon ECR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

I am using the cli and I want to push a docker image to AWS ECR. How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start by generating your login command using the [get-login-password](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecr/get-login-password.html) function.

Once you have logged in via the command, you would tag the image using

```
docker tag hello-world:latest aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world:latest
```

Finally you can push a docker image running the below command

```
docker push aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hello-world:latest
```

More information for pushing an image is available in [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-push-ecr-image.html).